# Animated Progress Bars with waypoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I'm trying to trigger the animation of my progress bars when scrolling to it using waypont.js

[image]

---

**JS**

```
function animateProgressBar(){
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
            .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $(this).data("origWidth")
            }, 1200);
    });
}

$(".meter > span").each(function() {
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
      element: $(this),
      handler: function(direction) {
        animateProgressBar();
      }
    });
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/x0gLw1aj/2)

I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: Waypoint is not defined` :(

Any hints / suggestions will be much appreciated !

Comment: Do you have a question? Here the jsfiddle animation work and waypoint.js is not involved so hard to know what exactly you need help with. [Documentation here](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) seems straight forward enough it's about setting your element targeted and calling your animation function in the handler.

Comment: I just not sure, how to integrated what I have with waypoint.js.

Comment: Should I integrated the waypoint within my `animateProgressBar()` ? or after ? Any  quick hint, will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your `animateProgressBar` function inside the `handler` method of your waypoint

```
function animateProgressBar(){
    $(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
            .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $(this).data("origWidth")
            }, 1200);
    });
}


var waypoint = new Waypoint({
      element: document.getElementById('thing'),
      handler: function(direction) {
        animateProgressBar();
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Trying it out now.

Comment: What should I replace on this line ? `element: document.getElementById('thing'),`

Comment: Replace 'thing' with the id of the container of your progress bars. The `handler` method will be triggered when you scroll on that container.

Comment: I already did that. Now, I got another small issue. "waypoint is defined, but never use."

Comment: example: replace `<div class="row">` with `<div class="row" id="meters">` , and in the javascript code : `element: document.getElementById('meters')`

Comment: I followed you and updated my post, please check it out.

Comment: I got a new warning now. `Uncaught ReferenceError: Waypoint is not defined`

Comment: Did you include the library ? Because I tried it and it works just fine : http://jsfiddle.net/x0gLw1aj/13/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89410/discussion-between-ihue-and-lyes-ben).